# Unable to push my local changes to remote in Gitlab

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

As per GitLab Documentation, I have generated the SSH Key in my machine (I use MAC). And then copied the SSH Key in remote Gitlab account under settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's likely the key has not been added to the local ssh-agent. Try `ssh-add "path to key file"` where the path is probably `~/.ssh/id_rsa` but yours may vary depending on how you created the original key.

Comment: Added still the issue continues

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/okXY8Hg.png